# PHP - PHPExcel loop through each row and call a web service and generate a new spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

Need help with looping through each row in the excel sheet and call a web service with an address and generate a new excel sheet with additional information. The web service will generate longitude and latitude, create a new sheet identical to the one you are reading from copy the longitude and latitude into the proper columns.

```
    <?php

require_once('PHPExcel.php');

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$excel = $reader->load($file);
$maxCol=$sheet->getHighestColumn();
$maxRow=$sheet->getHighestRow();


// loop through rows
for ($row=2; $row<=$maxRow; $row++) {
    // get address fields
    $street=$sheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue();
    $city=$sheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue();
    $state=$sheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue();
    $zip=$sheet->getCell("C$row")->getValue();

    $o = (object)[
        "street" => $street,
        "city" => $city,
        "state" => $state,
        "zip" => $zip
    ];

    $json = json_encode($o);

    // call webservice
    $response = file_get_contents("www.web.com/geolocate/keywords=".urlencode($json));

    $data = json_decode($response);

}
```

Comment: how do I import this data from the file_get_contents to the existing excel file

Comment: Parse $data to extract the values that you need; then create a new worksheet in the PHPExcel object and set cells to the values that you've parsed